# Plotly Choropleth map with Spain regions not displaying

Tags: python, plotly, geojson, choropleth, plotly-express

I am trying to use plotly express and chloropleth to display a map with Spanish autonomous regions, colored according to unemployment rates.
In order to do this, I am using a [dataframe with an ID for each region and the unemployement rate 'Tasa de desempleo'.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yldI.png) named 'df_indic_comunidades'

The region outlines are stored in a geojson file as multipolygons, which looks something like this:

```
{'features': [{'geometry': {'coordinates': [[[[-6.969706149311866,
    37.21774252292089],
   [-6.975248071819635, 37.21073261917811],
   [-6.958622304296327, 37.183501839254234],
   [-6.937193537266287, 37.183501839254234],
   [-6.944582767276646, 37.203992327117746],
   [-6.969706149311866, 37.21774252292089]]], ...
'type': 'MultiPolygon'}, 'properties': {'ENGTYPE_1': 'Autonomous Community',
'HASC_1': 'ES.AN',
'ID_1': 935,
'ISO': 'ESP',
'NAME_0': 'Spain',
'NAME_1': 'Andalucía',
'TYPE_1': 'Comunidad Autónoma',
'VARNAME_1': 'Andalousie|Andaluc¡a|Andalusien|Andaluzia'},'type': 'Feature'}, {'geometry': {'coordinates': [[[-0.7276540980614321, 42.91922077094266],
  [-0.753516403097688, 42.92461300459095],
  [-0.7830733231391207, 42.92164727608439
```

etc

I called this file 'comunidades'. This is my first time using json files and I am not very familiar with the structure, so that may be the problem.

**Each region is identifiable via 'ID_1' in the dataframe and properties.ID_1 in the json.**

I read the choropleth documentation and as far I understand I should be using featureid, but it is not working: I get a blank map, the json file does not seem to be read properly. This is the code I'm writing:

```
    fig = px.choropleth(data_frame=df_indic_comunidades, geojson=comunidades, locations='ID_1', color='Tasa de desempleo', color_continuous_scale='Viridis', labels={'Tasa de desempleo':'unemployment rate'}, range_color=(0, df_indic_comunidades['Tasa de desempleo'].max()),
                    featureidkey='properties.ID_1')
fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations")
fig.show()
```

and [this is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kC99l.png): everything is green so I can't see the outlines of the regions... but when hovering, I get the correct unemployment rates and regions

Why isn't the data displaying properly? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is the geojson file correct? I can't find any latitude/longitude information in the contents.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your commet. Indeed it was a topojson, which I converted to GeoJson using https://mapshaper.org/. The map now displays something green with a few outlines of the regions, so I think the geojson file is correct, but the data still isnt plotted correctly and I don't understand why.

Comment: Is it possible to share geojson? Do you have a sample data frame?